Get JSON from the server
since 2 days I try to make an "simple" code (if you know how). but for me impossible.
I have an php file like this:
try {
    $sql = $db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM myTable" );
    $sql->execute();
    
    
    if ( $sql->rowCount() > 0) {
        
        while ($result = $sql->fetch()) {
            
            $responseData [] = array(
                "date" => $result->date,
                "ml" => $result->ml
            );
    
        }
        

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($responseData);
        
    }
    
} catch (PDOException $e) { 
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

The response looks like this:

now I would like to create an tableview with swift, which execute this file and this this json data as data for the table. and this will not work for me.
I tried with the chatgpt support:
var myData:[String : Any]?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        sendPostRequest { jsonResponse, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Fehler beim Senden des POST-Requests: \(error)")
                return
            }


            self.myData = jsonResponse
            print("\(String(describing: self.myData))")
            
            //self.myTable.reloadData()
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = ""
        return cell
        
    }
    

}


func sendPostRequest(completion: @escaping ([String: Any]?, Error?) -> Void) {
    
    let apiUrl = URL(string: "https://myDomain.de/myFile.php")!


    var request = URLRequest(url: apiUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        // Überprüfe auf Fehler
        if let error = error {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }

        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
            let error = NSError(domain: "HTTP Error", code: (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? 0, userInfo: nil)
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }

        if let data = data {
            do {
                if let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                    completion(jsonResponse, nil)
                } else {
                    let error = NSError(domain: "JSON Error", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
            } catch {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }

    // Starte die Anfrage
    task.resume()
}

But I get this error:
Error Domain=JSON Error Code=0 "(null)"


Do not make the conversion during serialisation. So you can check the conversion status first and then what is the type of data the serialisation return

The error you're getting is  let error = NSError(domain: "JSON Error", code: 0, userInfo: nil), remove that, and instead return the error thrown by JSONSerialization. Remove that line totally. Also, print what you're receiving: print("(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")

but I guess that it's the as? [String: Any] which is failing as you're returning an Array, not a Dictionary?

Let's add some debugging steps:
guard let data = data else { return }
//Print what you received, because it might highlight that you didn't received expected output because of wrong request etc, so always check the validity of your response in case of error. I've seen plenty of error where responses are HTML error code or unexpected responses because of bad requests: missing parameter, header, wrong url, etc.
print("Received: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")

do {
    // If you do a if let, add an else to print it's not the expected unwrapping
    // Here since there was no error thrown, it might be due to as? [String: Any]
    let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    if let jsonDict = jsonDict as? [String: Any] {
        completion(jsonResponse, nil)
    } else {
       print("JSON Response is NOT a [String: Any]
    }
} catch {
    completion(nil, error)
}

Now, regarding your response, I strongly think that you response is an Array, so the as? [String: Any] fails, it should be as? [[String: Any]], as you have multiple objects.
You have a UITableView, so change the rest:
var myData: [[String : Any]]?
...

let object = myData[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = object["ml"] as? String
...


Now, regarding your parsing, I'd suggest you to use a custom struct instead of handling the data into Dictionary. Even better with a Codable struct.
struct Model: Codable {
    let ml: String
    let date: String
}
...
var myData: [Model]?
...
let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data)
completion(response, nil)
...
cell.textLabel?.text = myData[indexPath.row].ml

